# Unable to get oem unlock data

Tags: adb, fastboot, moto-x

I am dealing with a Motorola X4 that says "Your device is corrupt. It can't be trusted and will not boot." when ever I try to boot it up. I am able to get the device into fastboot mode, and I can use `fastboot` on my computer to see the device info, but when I try `./fastboot oem get_unlock_data` I get:

```
(bootloader) Failed to get unlock data.
OKAY [  0.002s]
Finished. Total time: 0.002s
```

And when I try `./fastboot oem unlock` I get:

```
(bootloader) Check 'OEM unlocking' in Android Settings > Developer
(bootloader) Options
OKAY [  0.001s]
Finished. Total time: 0.001s
```

Since the phone will not boot, I cannot turn it on to change the Android settings. I am also unable to get the device to be detected by `adb`. Is there anything else I can do from here to get the OEM unlock code?

Comment: Is it possible to perform a factory reset and then boot the device?

Comment: I have tried performing a factory reset from the fastboot menu but I get the same, "Your device is corrupt. It can't be trusted and will not boot." error. Is there another way to factory reset the device?